# View Model (StateObject) not deallocating in NavigationStack

Tags: swiftui

```swift
import SwiftUI

@MainActor
class MyModel: ObservableObject {
    let letvalue: Int
    @Published var value: Int

    init(_ value: Int) {
        print("init model \(value)")
        self.value = value
        self.letvalue = value
    }

    deinit {
        print("deinit model \(letvalue)")
    }
}


struct MyView: View {
    @StateObject var model: MyModel

    init(_ value: Int) {
        self._model = StateObject(wrappedValue: MyModel(value))
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello \(model.value)")
            NavigationLink(destination: {
                MyView(model.value + 1)
            }, label: {
                Text("goto \(model.value + 1)")
            })
        }
        .onAppear { [weak model] in
            print("onAppear \(model?.value)")
        }
        .onDisappear { [weak model] in
            print("onDisappear \(model?.value)")
        }
    }

}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            MyView(0)
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

When pressing the `NavigationLink` the previous models are never deallocated even tho the views disappear.

Here are the logs when pressing the `NavigationLink` a few times:

```
init model 0
deinit model 0
init model 0
onAppear Optional(0)
init model 1
onAppear Optional(1)
onDisappear Optional(0)
init model 2
onAppear Optional(2)
onDisappear Optional(1)
init model 3
onAppear Optional(3)
onDisappear Optional(2)
```

The models are not deallocated until going backwards in the navigation stack. I assume this is done to make navigating faster? However this is causing problems with more complex models with more resource intense objects not being deallocated or objects with pipeline limits (AVPlayer). I used a StateObject in this example but the same thing occurs for ObservedObject. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think the main issue is StateObject isn't designed for view models, you need to learn the View struct, State and Binding.

Comment: When using SwiftUI and value types we don't need to worry about object lifetimes. SwiftUI diffs the value types and it handles initing/de-initing/updating the UIView objects automatically.

Comment: Having a similar issue, `@StateObject` is not being deallocated if using NavigationStack with Hashable path, if I use NavigationStack with NavigationPath, it works fine and `@StateObject` is being deallocated correctly...